# Xively get datastream list from a feed using javascript

Tags: javascript, xively

I am trying to get the list of all datastream inside a single feed and show its current value. I am using the documentation here and tutorial : http://xively.github.io/xively-js/docs/. I tried to write a simple javascript code below, but its not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d23cj0cdvyoxg0.cloudfront.net/xivelyjs-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Xively Test</h1>
<h2>
<small>Datastream list</small>
</h2>
</p>
<script>
xively.setKey("yWYxyi3HpdqFCBtKHueTvOGoGROSAKxGRFAyQWk5d3JNdz0g");
xively.datastream.list(
    61916               //id from the tutorial example  
, function (data) {   
    data.results.forEach(function (datastream) {
        document.write("<br><br>Datastream ID:"+JSON.stringify(datastream["id"]
    document.write("<br><br>Current value:"+JSON.stringify(datastream["current_value"], null, 4));          
    });
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why is it not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some errors in your javascript

1. There is no results object in your data parameter.
2. Syntax error in your document.write statements

Try this code:

```
<script>
xively.setKey("yWYxyi3HpdqFCBtKHueTvOGoGROSAKxGRFAyQWk5d3JNdz0g");
xively.datastream.list(
    61916               //id from the tutorial example
, function (data) {
    data.forEach(function (datastream) {
        document.write("<br><br>Datastream ID:"+JSON.stringify(datastream["id"]));
        document.write("<br><br>Current value:"+JSON.stringify(datastream["current_value"], null, 4));
    });
});
</script>
```